# HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found - .NET - IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-10

This is my first time publishing a web forms project in ASP.NET. I have encountered may http error but this one i do not understand. My IIS version is 10.0

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
```

I i have seen a lot of solutions in the internet there is one in common and this is running

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i in cmd.
```

But I do get this error:

```
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
```

I check my .Net version and it is 3.5 and 4.8 on the `Turn windows features on/off`. I did select the 4.8 because if causes a lot of error. Or do I need to select it?

If I select the .Net 4.8 Version I get this error.

```
Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Which is easy to resolve? Or do I need to resolve both?

If you have any solutions please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _I check my .Net version and it is 3.5 and 4.8 on the Turn windows features on/off. I did select the 4.8 because if causes a lot of error. Or do I need to select it?_ please clarify? select or deselect?

Comment: I selected it now i am getting `Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.`

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019689/error-message-when-you-visit-a-web-site-that-is-hosted-on-iis-7-0-http

Comment: I already saw this and tried it already but no luck at all.

Comment: 404.17 also mean that a dynamic URL has been mapped to a static file handler. It always happen when your don't have a correct handler installed. So if you face this issue, you could check what you are loading and try to install the correct handler. Its glad that you have fixed this.

Answer (score 5):

Solved my problem.

1. Go to Turn windows feature on/off
2. Expand .NET Framework 4.8 Advanced
3. Services Expand WCF Services
4. Check HTTP Activation

Refresh Website and it should work!

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect, not sure why HTTP Activation under WCF while both asmx & wcf are different